# AbstractMethodError due to slf4j api and sl4j marker call apacheds-all-1.5.5

Tags: java, spring, logging

I landed on the famous error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:120)
```

After going thru a lot of SO questions here is my progress:

- `mvn.cmd dependency:tree -DskipTests | findstr /R /C:slf4j` proof that I'm using the same versions of slf4j on slf4j-api, jcl-over-slf4j (1.5.5, I can't use later versions coz of the following)
- looking for the classpath where some Classes are loaded from we see the following results:

  `debugJars(org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.class);`
  `debugJars(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.class);`
  `debugJars(org.slf4j.Marker.class);`

  `debugJars(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.class);`

Returns:

> file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-all/1.5.5/apacheds-all-1.5.5.jar!/org/slf4j/spi/
>
> file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.5/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.5.jar!/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/
>
> file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-all/1.5.5/apacheds-all-1.5.5.jar!/org/slf4j/
>
> file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/ch/qos/logback/classic/

How to get of rid of the fact that apacheds-all override my correct sl4j dependencies?

pom.xml doesn't include anything about appacheds-all dependency I understand that it may be an implicit dependency but how can I solve this?

Comment: I think the issue is some dependencies version mismatch between logback and slf4j, I would use slf4j 1.7.25 and logback-classic 1.2.2, see http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cch.qos.logback%7Clogback-parent%7C1.2.2%7Cpom

Comment: @RC to make this work I need to find a way to globally exclude appached to load its own version of slf4j (1.5.5) which is something that I dont know how to do

Comment: Use `<exclusion>` as shown in the answer below, you need to exclude all other version of slf4j (see your `mvn.cmd dependency:tree` output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also using the same dependency, I am not facing any issues
Can you try the following

```
<org.slf4j-version>1.5.5</org.slf4j-version>

<!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, new versions gets added automatically, do you have any idea on how to setup a global exclude or something to stop the loading of slf4j 1.5.5 from apached library (it's not included anywhere in my pom.xml)

Comment: I have changed my answer now, I hope it should work.